# python string uses special characters to send to c++ dll, crashes

Tags: c++, python, dll, special-characters

I have a python method calling a c++ dll method, that contains printf().

typical call:

```
method ("something")
```

But now I have to be able to call something like

```
method("%x %y %z")
```

And it is crashing.

I have escaped the %, with a very simple

```
if msg:            
    msg = msg.replace( "%", "/%" )
```

and it seemed to work for the case where there was only one. (Don't know exactly what effects it has on the text itself... )

So I tested with more than one, and I got a Debug Assertion Failure - Expression ("Incorrect format specifier", 0).

Edit: After the accepted answer, the solution:

```
if msg:            
   msg = msg.replace( "%", "%%" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to escape percent signs in `sprintf()` and the like is to double them (i.e. `%%`). But the code itself needs to be fixed by using `"%s"` as the first argument instead of the passed string.

Comment: I think this is what i need - but where ? instead of the const char ?

Comment: `sprintf("%s", variable_passed_in);`

Comment: I did: "char new_msg[80]; sprintf(new_msg, "%%s", msg);" And I got "%s". This is the right way to do it though isn't it ?

Comment: You've escaped your "%" in the "%s". You must not do that.

Answer (score 2):

**Backslashes** are escape characters. Try this:

```
if msg:            
  msg = msg.replace( "%", "\%" )
```

Your invalid format specifier error is from `%z or %y` not begin valid tokens.

---

What you're trying to do is a bit confusing. From what I can tell you're trying to do either this:

```
// Insert your string elements in python, before calling C functions.
method("%s %s %s" % ("Hello", "python", "world!")
```

Or this:

```
// Set the string format in python and pass to C function
method("%%s %%s %%s")

// In C function
char buf[128];
// Print your string with your custom format.
printf(GetStringFormatFromPython(), "Hello", "python", "world!");
```

Comment: sorry I copied wrong, that is what I had in my code (backslashes)

Comment: Ok. Well I think Ignacio has a good point about `printf` tokens. Are you trying to insert into your string python-side, or in c++? Because those tokens are still not valid in c++.

Comment: Thank you. I'll test, so far I have modified my python and got it going but I would like to do something in the c++ so the python could do whatever it wants. I appreciate your help.